# MVC 3: May I place the controllers in a dll?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

It really doesn't matter, but there's a reason why I want the controllers in a DLL file.

May I do that in an MVC project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a mvc project MvcApplication1.

create a mvc project MvcApplication2 and delete everything in it.

add reference to MvcApplication2 in MvcApplication1

create a HomeController inside MvcApplication2

create a view inside MvcApplication1

that's it.

Comment: "Thats it?"  - All you really need to create a class that inherits from Controller and reference System.Web.MVC. No need to create a new project and delete files.  A class library project works just fine.

Comment: true but then you won't have the visual studio helpers like "Add Controler"

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to modify the routes in global.asax, like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) { 
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");  
    routes.MapRoute( 
        name: "Default", 
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
        defaults: new { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }, 
        namespaces: new[] {
            typeof(HomeController).Namespace 
        } 
    ); 
}
```

Notice the additional namespaces argument to the MapRoute method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You don't have to do anything special.